# Serious issue while compiling

Tags: ubuntu-touch, compiling

So here i was, porting ubuntu touch, when suddenly this error pops up and i cant's really find a solution. it says "/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL"
please help me.
Much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your project is attempting to link with [libGL](https://dri.freedesktop.org/wiki/libGL/) and cannot find it either because it is not present on your system, or because you have not provided the appropriate compile/link flags or environment variables (e.g., `LIBRARY_PATH`) to allow the linker to locate it.

Comment: any help on how to do it!?(Sorry for being such a newbie...)